# ASP NET WebApp fails after publishing because of code contracts

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, code-contracts

I've got an ASP.NET WebApp which uses code contracts. I'm publishing my app to the server and get the following exception:

> An assembly (probably "xxxxxx") must be rewritten using the code contracts binary rewriter (CCRewrite) because it is calling Contract.Requires and the CONTRACTS_FULL symbol is defined.

However Code Contract is installed on my Visual Studio and the "Contracts Full" is disabled for all projects.
What may cause the exception?

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned that Visual Studio 2015 poorly supports code contracts.